# Autofill Form with the ability of entry of new records in the selected fields ms-access-2016

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

I am currently trying to make a database titled invoice management system for an organization who provide services in different departments. I have created three tables.[Tables used in database with fields.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqRCI.png)

I have then created a query to create an autofill form based on Alias from InvoiceTable and all other fields from AttentionTable except Alias. [Autofill Form with Alias from IvoiceTable and rest of the fields from AttentionTable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EE6o4.png) Alias in InvoiceTable is a combo box whose data source is Alias in AttentionTable. I just want to select Alias (InvoiceTable) from this form to automatically fill the rest of the fields of AttentionTable. Till that point I am successfull. But, I also want to add new record of AttentionTable from this form if the record is not available in the Alias dropdown list. I have tried multiple ways but in vain. I know that i can't enter new record in Alias field because Alias is a foreign key in InvoiceTable. Is there anyway to enter new record in foreign key and update the primary key with this record as I can't enter new records in this field if I need to enter a new record for attention table? I hope you got my point. (Althought I have created new form for first entering record for Attention table and then use this form, but I want All in one in this form)

I hope you help me to resolve my issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Probably this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215255/how-can-a-free-tagging-field-be-created-in-a-microsoft-access-form/41216045#41216045

Comment: Thanks a lot @SergeyS..what changes do we need to make in this code if its 100% sure that user want to add the data. I mean if there is no prompt. just enter the data, if it is not in the list, it should be added automatically.

Comment: It works like described - user enters text not existing in dropdown and when user tries to go out from field, Access fires NotInList event. There we ask user if he really wants to add entered text. If yes, we add it. If you need to ask additional data, just open a form form, collect required data and insert it into table.

Comment: Used it but didn't work. Thanks BTW @SergeyS.